# Which view within row of listview is clicked/touched?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a listview with each row containing 2 linearlayouts, say LL1 & LL2.

Both LL1 & LL2 have different functionality on clicking. But I cannot make make any of the LL clickable (using android:clickable="true") because that would stop the listview's OnItemClickListener(required to find the position of the row) from firing.

So basically I want to use

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
        // required to find the position of the row 
        }
    });
```

So using the above function only, how can I find which LinearLayout was clicked??

Comment: Why do you want to use OnItemClickListener to get the position ? You will get the position from the getView method! So using the position you can write the click listeners to each of the  LL.

Comment: How?? using listView.getPositionForView(view); ?? I think it will work out but still wanted to know how to do this using setOnItemClickListener()

Answer (score 0):

like this:

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,int position, long id) {
        if(v.getid == R.id.linearlayout1){

        }else if(v.getid == R.id.linearlayout2){

       }
    }
});
```

Comment: v.getId() will fetch the ID of the entire row which can never match any of its children layout's ID...n I tried this before posting the question